# In AWS find all files in s3 bucket with filename containing number greater than specific value & copy them to EC2

Tags: unix, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

In AWS S3 bucket I have filenames of the format 
`abc_10005_def.dat.gz` 
where `10005` is the id within the filename.

> I need to copy files where the respective id is > 10001 from S3 to EC2
>   one by one.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the names of the object you can use the aws s3 cli inside a bash script

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/abc_1000X_def.dat.gz  abc_1000X_def.dat.gz`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

Install AWS CLI

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html